# Excel WorkbookGuid creation source?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working with a series of spreadsheets/workbooks and noticed that a few of the submitted spreadsheets have a WorkbookGuid with a string:

```
ddc-481f-afd8-8322f6e65346
```

in the custom properties. I've looked everywhere I can imagine and cannot find any reference to what might be creating this string id. I'd like to know what creates it, when, and why.

Comment: VBA uses GUIDs for all sorts of reasons ...